# LogCat doesn't show my own logs in real device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide, android-logcat

I have little test app in Android Studio with strange behavior regarding LogCat:
For example I have logs like this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        ...
```

If I try to start my app in emulator, all my logs work fine.
But if I try to start my app on a real device, I can see a lot of system logs from my device(for example from BatteryService), but there are none of my own logs here.

I have enabled ADB integration  and source of logs in LogCat choosed right(my device).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem.
Strange behavior of LogCat was because of API version of my device Android was lower than required API version of my app.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you already have USB debugging activated(othervise it will not work).

 Open logcat and press the launch button. and as it goes to your device it should work normally. Now, if you are using the APK from google drive, the app store or anywhere else it will not work as debug access isn't there.

If you have done the above, you can try this method:

[image]

As you can see, there is a search box next to the 'Log level' dropdown menu. Search for your app(in format of a package name) and it will show up. From there, you can select a log level(if you feel like it). If you do not chose a log level and set it to verbose, all logs will show up, all types of log level.

And if that does not work, we can definitivly conclude with the fact that it is *NOT* USB debugging related. Then it might be because of configurations in build.gradle files, the Android Manifest, or maybe in the code. Also, in my experience, Proguard prevents log output, but you get output just not from your app. So if none of the above worked, check:

- Android min version(by what your app can handle)
- Android target version(in comparison with the newest current API which is right now 24)
- (the same in build.gradle on app level)
- Proguard on/off

And finally, if none of that works, download ACRA and convert the logs using the simplest backend(10 lines) and you have the logs on your website upon crash in .txt format. It is a hard workaround but at least you will be able to read any crashes.

Comment: What did you mean when you said "Open logcat". Logcat start automatically by Android Studio. I can't find any separate launcher.
I am nood at Android, can you help me with it?

Comment: By "Open logcat" I mean you you make it so you see the output area for LogCat. If you want to see it working, connect your device with USB debugging(let me know if you have no idea what that is) and cause a nullpointer. AS long as it happens when the device is connected, LogCat will direct you to the error on your computer.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-the-USB-Debugging-Mode-on-Samsung-Galaxy-S3-and-Newer-Models or http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-USB-Debugging-Mode-on-Android-Devices to activate USB debugging

Comment: My USB debugging turn on and I get this with nullpointer:
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ccd930)
Also I can debug app started on my device.

Comment: can you update the question to include the full stacktrace?

Comment: It's ok now(I found a problem, just forgot to wrote about it).
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Check for the `dropdown` in `LogCat` and change the option to Debug or D.

Being you have put your logs in `Log.d("TAG","MSG");`

Options are

1. Verbose
2. **debug** . *Your logs will appear in this case*
3. info
4. warn
5. error
6. assert

Comment: It doesn't help (I have try it before writing a post).
I also try to create my own filter for it. It works with emulator, but not ith real device.

Comment: Hope you have enabled the developer options as well. Try connecting the device and see if you are able to view the mass memory through computer. Directly run your build after clean and rebuild the project

Comment: you right. It's some problem here - I can see only my SD-card throught computer, not embeded memory.

Comment: Switch between MTP and PTP  and try. Go through this link http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/

Comment: I can use embeded memory in MTP and PTP, but I can't start my App with it.

Comment: change to Log.i  or Log.v  and try again from start. Probably you can restart Android studio/Eclipse. Sometimes it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

try this on your andorid device!

Performance Optimization - Advanced Log Output